# What is the cookie called google_cid?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I am searching for the description of a Cookie called `google_cid` .  What is it used for and does it have any expiry?

I have tried searching on [Google Analytics Cookie Usage on Websites](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage)  and search engines in general but unable it identify the source.

Comment: Do you have an example? This doesn't seem to be a cookie set by Google Automatically. In Google Analytics one has the option to rename the cookie that GA uses by default, maybe that's it, but would need an example to confirm.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could rename cookie. I am able now to establish that the expiry is set to 'session' only and according to a report it is a google analytics cookie.  But I don't have any more information than this.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a custom cookie solution. This type of naming is usually set as a function return when querying for the client ID. Google cid is usually the clientID identifier of the GA cookies. It is used to identify unique users in browsers and used in server-side sessionalization at Google to create unique users, session stitching etc.